# Javascript Level/XP bar not working properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, windows-xp, percentage

I am making a XP bar with a current xp value and a max xp value and came up with a script to function it. Here is my markup:

```
<div class="meter">
    <span id="XP" style="width:0px">
        <div id="level"></div>
    </span>
</div>
```

and here is my Script:

```
var currentXP=0;
var maxXP=745;
var gainXP=5;
var level=1;
percentage = (currentXP / maxXP) * 100;
document.getElementById("XP").style.width = percentage;
document.getElementById("level").innerHTML="Level : " + level;
function XPBar() {
    if (currentXP != maxXP) {
        currentXP += gainXP;
        document.getElementById("XP").style.width = percentage;
    }
    if (currentXP == maxXP) {
        currentXP -= maxXP;
        currentXP += gainXP;
        level++;
        document.getElementById("level").innerHTML="Level : " + level;
        Orbs+=1;
        document.getElementById("XP").style.width = percentage;
    }
}
```

The main thing is to resize the bars width according to the percentage of the required xp. In this case, its maxXP. It does not work and i dont know why.

Comment: Could you explain more how it doesn't work?  What is the desired behavior, and what do you get instead?

Comment: The behavior is explained already as re-sizing the div's width according to the percentage. The percentage is calculated as of here: `percentage = (currentXP / maxXP) * 100;` and here: `document.getElementById("XP").style.width = percentage;`

Comment: Fair enough. What happens instead? (Maybe post a jsFiddle so we can see?)

Comment: What happens instead is that it should add 5 XP to the bar which would be the gainXP. Ill try creating a fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to understand what you want and then created the following [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qPYCB/). I hope it contains the core of what you want.

I think the main problem was missing `'%'` in
`document.getElementById("XP").style.width = percentage + '%';`

Comment: your fiddle is blank.

Comment: sorry about that. I have edited the link, it should work now.